# Question on my JavaScript with a tax problem

Tags: java

I am trying to get some help on a JavaScript I am creating to calculate tax. Feel like something is wrong with my math but I think the code is working as intended. When I input the 2 values the math which comes out doesn't appear to be accurate. If anyone could take a look at it and see what is wrong in my work, that'd be much appreciated.

```
package taxableIncome;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class taxableIncome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter filing status: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = input.nextDouble();
        if (x == 0) {
            x = 'S';
        } else if (x == 1) {
            x = 'M';
        } else if (x == 2) {
            x = 'J';
        } else if (x == 3) {
            x = 'H';
            }

        System.out.println("Enter taxable income: ");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double y = input.nextInt();
        if (x == 'S') {
        if (y <= 8350) {
            System.out.println(y*.01);
        } else if (y >= 8351 && y<= 33950) {
            System.out.println(y*.15);
        } else if (y >= 33951 && y<= 82250) {
            System.out.println(y*.25);
        } else if (y >= 82251 && y<= 171550) {
            System.out.println(y*.28);
        } else if (y >= 171551 && y<= 372950) {
            System.out.println(y*.33);
        } else System.out.println(y*.35);
        }
        if (x == 'M') {
        if (y <= 8350) {
            System.out.println(y*.01);
        } else if (y >= 8351 && y<= 33950) {
            System.out.println(y*.15);
        } else if (y >= 33951 && y<= 68525) {
            System.out.println(y*.25);
        } else if (y >= 68526 && y<= 104425) {
            System.out.println(y*.28);
        } else if (y >= 104426 && y<= 186475) {
            System.out.println(y*.33);
        } else System.out.println(y*.35);
        }
        if (x == 'J') {
        if (y <= 16700) {
            System.out.println(y*.01);
        } else if (y >= 16701 && y<= 67900) {
            System.out.println(y*.15);
        } else if (y >= 67901 && y<= 137050) {
            System.out.println(y*.25);
        } else if (y >= 137051 && y<= 208850) {
            System.out.println(y*.28);
        } else if (y >= 208851 && y<= 372950) {
            System.out.println(y*.33);
        } else System.out.println(y*.35);
        }
        if (x == 'H') {
        if (y <= 11950) {
            System.out.println(y*.01);
        } else if (y >= 11951 && y<= 45500) {
            System.out.println(y*.15);
        } else if (y >= 45501 && y<= 117450) {
            System.out.println(y*.25);
        } else if (y >= 117451 && y<= 190200) {
            System.out.println(y*.28);
        } else if (y >= 190201 && y<= 372590) {
            System.out.println(y*.33);
        } else System.out.println(y*.35);
}

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add details on the calculation you're trying to achieve here. Without information about that, how are we supposed to know what's wrong?

Comment: Is it because of double taxableIncome = input.nextInt(); ?

Comment: Please provide more details as to what you mean by "wrong". For example, is the output consistently higher than expected, consistently lower, etc?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code isn't something the other programmer (your potential co-worker) like to read.

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.io  Take care in spelling *JavaScript*.

Answer (score 1):

1. I change the output to give a hint to user to what he can input.
2. Instead of reading a double change it to store the first character since thats what you use to determin the status.
3. renamed your x and y because I can't remember what all the x and y mean.
4. read double from user input instead of int.

---

```
public class taxableIncome {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter filing status (S,M,J,H): ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char status = input.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Enter taxable income: ");
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double taxableIncome = input.nextDouble();
    if (status == 'S') {
      if (taxableIncome <= 8350) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .01);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 8351 && taxableIncome <= 33950) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .15);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 33951 && taxableIncome <= 82250) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .25);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 82251 && taxableIncome <= 171550) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .28);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 171551 && taxableIncome <= 372950) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .33);
      } else
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .35);
    }
    if (status == 'M') {
      if (taxableIncome <= 8350) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .01);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 8351 && taxableIncome <= 33950) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .15);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 33951 && taxableIncome <= 68525) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .25);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 68526 && taxableIncome <= 104425) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .28);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 104426 && taxableIncome <= 186475) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .33);
      } else
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .35);
    }
    if (status == 'J') {
      if (taxableIncome <= 16700) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .01);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 16701 && taxableIncome <= 67900) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .15);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 67901 && taxableIncome <= 137050) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .25);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 137051 && taxableIncome <= 208850) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .28);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 208851 && taxableIncome <= 372950) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .33);
      } else
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .35);
    }
    if (status == 'H') {
      if (taxableIncome <= 11950) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .01);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 11951 && taxableIncome <= 45500) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .15);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 45501 && taxableIncome <= 117450) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .25);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 117451 && taxableIncome <= 190200) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .28);
      } else if (taxableIncome >= 190201 && taxableIncome <= 372590) {
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .33);
      } else
        System.out.println(taxableIncome * .35);
    }
  }
}
```